# How to create typeahead feature in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CSS
TypeAhead

I am trying to create a comboBox in HTML and JavaScript.

So I create an input field and then inside the input field I created a table. On click of input I am getting a drop down where my table is getting displayed. I can select the td value from table.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
Myocombo = function(args) {
    var dataUrl = args.url;
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    var myTable = '<input type="text" style="width:30%;" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">' +
        '<table id="myTable">' + '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>' + '</table>';
    div.innerHTML = myTable;
    function foo(callback) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json", true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }
    // Getting data from URL
    foo(function(data) {
        debugger;
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_opt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < jsonc.length; i++) {
            new_opt += '<tr><td>' + jsonc[i]['VALUE'] + '</td></tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = new_opt;
        document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)').forEach(function(_tr) {
            _tr.addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.getElementById('myInput').value += " ; " + this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
            });
        });
    });
    // Displaying the table name
    myFunction = function() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want a typeahead feature. Meaning if I type anything other td value can filter and show those values only. How can I do that?

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <title>PC-AutoCombo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Myocombo .css">
    <script src="js/Myocombo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="Line">Line</option>
        <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <div id="chart_line" style = "position: relative;"></div>

</body>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            switch(val){
                case 'Line' :
                    var myCombo = new Myocombo ({
                      "url": "data.json",
                      "divID": "chart_line",
                    });
                    break;
                case 'Bar' :
                    var myCombo = new Myocombo ({
                      "url": "data.json",
                      "divID": "chart_line",
                    });
                    break;

            }
    }
</script>
```

Is there any jQuery way by which I can get this?

My JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "ID" : 0,
        "VALUE" : "United State"
    },{
        "ID"  : 1,
        "VALUE" : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        "ID"  : 2,
        "VALUE" : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        "ID"  : 3,
        "VALUE" : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        "ID"  : 4,
        "VALUE" : "Albania"
    },{
        "ID" : 5,
        "VALUE" : "United State"
    },{
        "ID"  : 6,
        "VALUE" : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        "ID"  : 7,
        "VALUE" : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        "ID"  : 8,
        "VALUE" : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        "ID"  : 9,
        "VALUE" : "Albania"
    },{
        "Data" : "Hello"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think for this, the easiest way is to use 3rd party libraries such as this one: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: @ThomasJamesTiam-Lee This will be again a new set of work and I want to make it in javascript

Comment: You can use JQuery Autocomplete widget. here is the short dynamic auto-complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390442/trying-to-implement-live-search-in-a-input-box/44390747#44390747. hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you post your **html** code. or **include a snippet** in your question?

Comment: Can you share the link for **Myocombo.js**? it's helpful to create a fiddle and solve it.

Comment: Wait let me try to create a fiddle. Give me some 5 minutes

Comment: @MrASquare I created a fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenal/dgLf8x3j/1/ Don't know how to add json. Let me add tha

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery's UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)...

```
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

Comment: Thanks for ANswer. Can you please also let me know how this implement in my JS code. Thanks

Comment: Just have a look at the documentation supplied in the link. It is really straight forward.